# How to enable sqlite in Apache php

Tags: apache, sqlite

I have a php sqlite app I cannot make work locally offline .

I downloaded from https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/

I installed MySQL myphpadmin apache2 and sqlite

I am not able to get the DB stuff to run because the app uses sqlite files.

I am not familiar with these tools and I want to run these locally as a user and then tell my friend who is less skilled to do the same.  It is really for him.  I have php MySQL myphpadmin and Apache running fine.  I just need to have the DB work now.

How to do this?

I would prefer not to use xammp be because it is not standard repo stuff but if it really simplifies things you can include that.

We want to make it work offline (Ubuntu) because this monastery wants to be offline as much as possible.  (It is a Sanskrit app)

Comment: In order to enable SQLite in PHP/Apache, you have to install the SQLite PHP extension: sudo apt install php-sqlite and restart the web server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I already have php-sqlite3 installed to the latest version.  But the DB is still not accessibe
 By the php code.

Comment: I am not sure but I made a phpinfo page and I can see sqlite loaded.  Is there some type of conf file I need to know nckude in the web app for?